# Django: capture authorization token from another service

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm trying to capture an authentication token from another service authenticator. In summary, I have a form login that serve client with two options to sign in, throw the normal login, or a link to a second authenticator service which will redirect to a particular form page. Once the user is signed, this second authenticator service will redirect back to my application, with a token as param.

I would like to include a kind of listener in my application (small script), in a way that when this redirect happen, I could capture and validate the token, finally, authenticate the user in the local django application.

Comment: It's called [Implicit flow](https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/flows/implicit-flow-with-form-post). You've to setup a webhook in your app and in your view you've to capture the query params and get to Authorization token and validate it. If it's ok redirect to another view and keep the token in user's session. If not abort the request and redirect to login view.

Comment: Cool @ChihebNexus! Did not know the name! Now is much better to search for examples! Thank you for the tip. I will try to do so!

Comment: I would need to intercept the request toward my application from external server (which is exatcly my doubt, how to do that in django, middleware, javascript in frontend?), because it does not happen automatically. My application is listening in 8000 port. Right after to authenticate in this external link, there is a redirect to the application such as myapp.com/?token=XXXX. Im just confused about the traffic beyond the two servers, and the right way to implement it in django ecossystem

Answer (score 0):

I just came out with a simple solution since I was searching for an automatic capturing of a request. So, considering that the external authentication server redirect to a preinformed URL right after to authenticate, this URL could be capture in my localhost application by editing `/etc/hosts` AND `nginx.conf` (as suggest [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/mapping-hostnames-ports)), not just one or another. So, the first:

```
127.0.0.1 url-redirect-by-external-server.com
```

and `nginx.conf`, I have added a new `server` properties to the file:

```
...

server {
    listen 80;  
    listen 443;
    server_name url-redirect-by-external-server.com;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/exact-name-of-the-method-in-view-to-handle-the-request/;
    }    
}
...
```

The point is, when the request is made by the external server, the app still does not capture. When I press `Enter` to the URL, then, everything runs fine. Still did not figure what should be set.